# Heath Jarrow Morton Framework

Tags: models, rates

Can someone please explain Heath Jarrow Morton framework ? Why do we use it ? I understand the logic between equilibrium models and no arbitrage models but i'm struggling to understand the added value of HJM framework...

Answer (score 3):

Posting as answer as too long for a comment.

There are at least two reasons why HJM is attractive:

1. By construction HJM can fit the initial term structure, not all short rate models can (and furthermore the instantaneous short rate is not really observable in contrast to forward rates)
2. HJM can accommodate the wildest movements of the term structure (through a flexible correlation structure)

A third more 'soft' reason: it is beautiful, and models should be beautiful (as financial models are gender neutral I believe I am staying within politically correct boundaries).

HJM has its issues though: it is in general non-Markovian and infinite dimensional, making it a difficult to use in practice. 'Discrete' modifications of HJM such as the Libor Market Model and Swap Market Model (SMM) address some of its practical implementation issues.

Comment: Best answer.. but can you please explain when we use this models ? simple example